# Можно ли вставлять сразу всю строку при использовании MERGE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В статье нашел пример использования:

```
MERGE INTO person p
   USING (   SELECT tabn, name, age FROM person1) p1
   ON (p.tabn = p1.tabn)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET p.age = p1.age     
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (p.tabn, p.name, p.age)
    VALUES (p1.tabn, p1.name, p1.age)
```

У меня порядка 100 столбцов в таблице. Можно ли сразу писать при не совпадении что-то вроде:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT p.row
    VALUES (p1.row)
```

То есть вставлять сразу всю строку?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под p.row? это название столбца? или словом row вы заменяете перечень из 100 столбцов?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Именно так, перечень из 100 столбцов. Это скорее псевдокод чтобы дать представление о том, что хотелось бы видеть.

Comment: вы можете не указывать перечень столбцов вот тут - WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT, но в VALUES перечень столбцов - обязателен. В любом случае, использование insert без перечисления столбцов - плохая идея.

Comment: вот похожий вопрос на enso - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944969/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-without-naming-all-columns

Comment: Вас не удовлетворило предложенное решение? Возможны и друугие, например, автоматически генерировать лист колонок из мета данных прямо в код.

Comment: @0xdb если я правильно понял, предложенное решение сугубо на plsql, а хочется иметь на руках именно запрос. Возможно, ответа нет вовсе.

Comment: Ответ есть - он до разделительной линии в моём ответе - желаемое не не возможно. Что вы понимаете под - "сугубо на plsql"? А где вы вызываете ваш запрос?

Comment: @0xdb Например, в каком-нибудь SQLplus. Я могу отметить ваш ответ как верный чтобы вопрос не остался висеть открытым, но это не совсем то, что я искал в тот момент. 
p.s. Я тогда просто скопировал описание таблицы в эксель и сгенерировал запрос на merge. Самое быстрое решение было в той ситуации.

Comment: Я и вызывал предложеный пример в sqlplus. То что вы ищете должно быть указано в вопросе.  В вопросе же вы пожелали, не использовать листы, а ожидали, как я понял из последнего комментария, сгеннерировать листы быстрейшим способом. Я не могу и не хочу навязывать своего решения, смею только заметить, что подобное решение было проверено и работает в продуктивной среде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, так нельзя. Предложение [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) этого не допускает.

---

Если такой вопрос возник, то таблицы полностью совпадают.
В таком случае сделайте свой `MERGE`:

```
create table person1 as 
    select rownum id, 'name '||rownum  name from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
create table person2 as select * from person1 where 0=1;    

create or replace function mergePerson return number is
    type rowsType is table of person1%rowtype;
    rows rowsType;
begin
    select * bulk collect into rows 
    from person1 p1
    where not exists (select 1 from person2 p2 where p2.id = p1.id)
    ;
    forall n in 1..rows.count insert into person2 values rows (n);
    return sql%rowcount;
end;
/

exec dbms_output.put_line (mergePerson||' rows merged')

3 rows merged
```

С добавлением `update` не должно возникнуть трудностей.